# npx create-next-app produces error on npm run dev, npm start and npm run build

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

I installed next.js with npx create-next-app, so its fresh and installed via command. When I try to run the dev server, the server starts on localhost:3000 but when I open it in browser it displays in top left corner "Internal Server Error" without next.js styling.

I tried deleting the npm cache, I checked for npm and node versions, all is fine but next just does not work.

I even tried npm install --save react react-dom next, it also does not work with npm run dev etc.

*** npm start log ***

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.8
3 info using node@v12.18.2
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle test@0.1.0~prestart: test@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle test@0.1.0~start: test@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle test@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle test@0.1.0~start: PATH: C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\hp\desktop\ssr\test\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\hp\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Users\hp\bin;C:\Python38\Scripts;C:\Python38;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\PuTTY;C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\vendor_perl;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\core_perl
9 verbose lifecycle test@0.1.0~start: CWD: C:\Users\hp\desktop\ssr\test
10 silly lifecycle test@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'next start' ]
11 silly lifecycle test@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle test@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: test@0.1.0 start: `next start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
14 verbose pkgid test@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\hp\desktop\ssr\test
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18363
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v12.18.2
19 verbose npm  v6.14.8
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error test@0.1.0 start: `next start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the test@0.1.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Did you run "next build" before "next start"?

Comment: No, that is fresh install just to produce the error

Comment: Did you run `next dev` directly instead of `npm run dev`?

Comment: I did not try that

Comment: @ErmeSchultz same problem

Comment: Did you installed nextjs globally before run `next dev`?

Comment: I fixed the issue by installing node-fetch latest beta version and deleted package-lock file.